# Npm install Error | 69 vulnerabilities (12 low, 28 moderate, 26 high, 3 critical)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Hey Guy's Help Me plase To solve this problem ...!
*My Problem is :*

```
> npm i 
up to date, audited 1879 packages in 13s

90 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

69 vulnerabilities (12 low, 28 moderate, 26 high, 3 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

*More Info :*

1. **Npm Version : 8.13.2**
2. **OS : Windows**
3. **Node : v18.4.0**

**WARNING : npm audit fix --force NOT WORKING**

**WARNING : This error for Update and Install !!**

[Screenshot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOCcu.png)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine as long as there are no security vulnerabilities, in that case you can use this package [npm force resolutions](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions)

Comment: This is Not Fixed My Error ! yes My npm work fine but have this i want to fix that ... Thank You !.

Answer (score 0):

I had those issues as well, and if `npm audit fix --force` is not working then I suggest running just `npm audit` you will get detailed information about what is wrong and what should be updated hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm Command in visual studio
`npm install npm@latest -g`